# How Ghostery classification works?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, firefox-addon, privacy, adblock

Gostery promises to preserve user privacy by blocking trackers (analytics, advertisers, widgets, etc). I would like to know, other than manual aggregation or crawling, how they collected the list of all trackers and how the classify(labeled) them as analytics, advertisers, widgets, etc?

- http://www.knowyourelements.com/#tab=intro&date=2014-05-01

Comment: This question can only be answered by the Ghostery developers.